# How to get the correct information from every file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code below works, where it recursively map the paths and scans all files outputting their information such as file size, last access, last modified and when it was created. However, the information is incorrect where it doesn't output what is displayed for every specific files from their properties. Is there a way to retrieve the correct information from the files?

Below is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)

pop={}

output = 'C:\\Users\\'
starting_dir='X:\\'
print(starting_dir)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(starting_dir):
    print(root)
    with os.scandir(root) as i:
        for entry in i:
            file_size = round((os.path.getsize(entry) / 1048576), 4)
            print(file_size)
            access_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getatime(entry)))
            print(access_time)
            modify_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(entry)))
            print(modify_time)
            created_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(entry)))
            print(created_time)
            pop[root]= 'Directory|' + str(file_size) + '|'+ str(access_time)+'|'+ str(modify_time) +'|'+ str(created_time)
        for name in files:
            da_file=os.path.join(root,name)
            pop[da_file]= name + '|'+  str(file_size) + '|'+ str(access_time) +'|'+ str(modify_time) +'|'+ str(created_time)

print('Scan Complete!')

dfr=pd.DataFrame(pop.items(),columns=['file_location','combo'])

dfr['file_name'] = dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[0]
dfr['file_size'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[1]).astype(float)
dfr['last_access']= (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[2])
dfr['last_modify'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[3])
dfr['created'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[4])

dfr.to_excel(output + 'sharepoint_output.xlsx',index=False)

print('Output Ready!')
```

Comment: In what way is it 'incorrect' what output do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: Why are you writing a pipe separated list to a variable, only to immediately split it back out into a df? Surely writing that directly to the df would be easier and more efficient?

Comment: Hi @JffUK, what is shown in the properties in file explorer is not the same as what is outputted when I run the python code. Like the output will say one file is 10MB but the properties in file explorer will say the file size is 30MB. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Hi, as I mentioned i am walking across files and subfolders to get their properties and output it as a data frame in excel. However it is not visiting every file correctly, the answer below is what i am looking for, but when i run the code below, it gives a blank output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not visiting every file correctly.
In the second block of your code you are using the values that were set in the first block. So these values match the last file that was visited via scandir, not the file you are currently making an entry for, which is the file from the walk.

I don't think you need to use scandir at all, just the walk, perhaps like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

def make_entry(pop,root,name):
    full_name = os.path.join(root,name)
    file_size = round((os.path.getsize(full_name) / 1048576), 4)
    access_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getatime(full_name)))
    modify_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(full_name)))
    created_time = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(full_name)))
    pop[full_name]= name + '|'+  str(file_size) + '|'+ str(access_time) +'|'+ str(modify_time) +'|'+ str(created_time)
    print(pop[full_name])


def main():
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)

    pop={}

    output = 'C:\\Users\\'
    starting_dir='X:\\'
    print(starting_dir)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(starting_dir):
        for dir in dirs:
            make_entry(pop,root,dir)
        for name in files:
            make_entry(pop,root,name)

    print('Scan Complete!')

    dfr=pd.DataFrame(pop.items(),columns=['file_location','combo'])

    dfr['file_name'] = dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[0]
    dfr['file_size'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[1]).astype(float)
    dfr['last_access']= (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[2])
    dfr['last_modify'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[3])
    dfr['created'] = (dfr['combo'].str.split('|').str[4])

    dfr.to_excel(output + 'sharepoint_output.xlsx',index=False)

    print('Output Ready!')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that but it outputs just the headers on the spreadsheet, not the details and information for each file